# how to correctly call my rest api from ajax javascript Client

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I have a REST API and I am wanting to invoke it from my ajax javascript client.

I make the call and nothing happends.  My mobile browser just indicates 'busy'.

No error is returned.

This is my code behind:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Services/Image/Validate")]
public byte Validate(string KeyCode)
{
    return 1;
}
```

this is my JavaScript client:

```
$("#btnValidate").click(function () {
    try {            
        var url = "http://MY_DOMAIN_NAME/api/Services/Image/Validate";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: '{ "KeyCode" : "' + $("#KeyCode").val() + '" }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {
                $('#divStep1').hide();
                $('#divStep2').show();
            },
            fail: function (a) {
                $("#error").html(objRequest);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        $("#error").html(ex);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: every thing is correct. what is logged in console?

Comment: ah, a nit tricky to check as I am using my mobile browser and it is a iPhone and i have no iMac :(

Comment: dumb thing to say. just run it through a desktop browser and the error is

Comment: 404 not found for some reason

Comment: i think your url path should be causing the trouble, check the path is correct or not

Comment: I have removed the 'api' routing tag. The error thrown now is : Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Answer (score -1):

The catch function with throw an error only when the HTTP request fails. In Order to know wha'ts going wrong in the server side code you need to use the `error` function in the ajax request,

You also mentioned that the browser does nothing and this might happen due to

1. jQuery plugin not included in the page (check console for `$ is not defined`)
2. Add the jquery plugin above your javascript
3. If your server side code is on a different domain enable `CORS`

   ```
   $("#btnValidate").click(function () {       
    var url = "http://MY_DOMAIN_NAME/api/Services/Image/Validate";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: '{ "KeyCode" : "' + $("#KeyCode").val() + '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#divStep1').hide();
            $('#divStep2').show();
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.responseText); //Acutal error
            console.log(e); //Get the entire error details
        }
    });
   });
   ```

Comment: hi, JQuery plugin is linked in

Comment: not a different domain. It is OK I have done the basics :)

Comment: Cheers :) If you are working with jQuery you could always use the console to check what's going wrong especially the network's `xhr` tab for ajax requests!

Answer (score -1):

The settings object you are sending to `$.Ajax()` does not expect a `fail` parameter. Maybe you are confusing promises?

Anyway, it should probably be `error`.
eg.

```
$("#btnValidate").click(function () {
    try {            
        var url = "http://MY_DOMAIN_NAME/api/Services/Image/Validate";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: '{ "KeyCode" : "' + $("#KeyCode").val() + '" }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {
                $('#divStep1').hide();
                $('#divStep2').show();
            },
            error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#error").html(textStatus);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        $("#error").html(ex);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Also, I'm not sure if you should have the `data` property as a string but maybe this is how you want it.

All documentation on this is [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: thanks for link.  Yes I am aware of that page. It was a copy and paste error in regards to the ajax error handling

Comment: Yes it is, he has to use `error` instead of `fail`. Same as the other answer (which were posted at the same time). Both of which you seem to have downvoted.